# Communication between Java and applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet

How do I get the (updated) value of Java Class's variable which is dynamically modified from an applet?

The problem here is, since the applet is loaded in separate class loaders the updated value is not available when the applet is loaded a second and subsequent times.

Comment: Do you mean server side Java, or JavaScript as your tag indicate?

Comment: In fact simple desktop java....java script is there to indicate the use of applet by the java script from an html page

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve - are there two classes, one in an applet and another, where?

Comment: Is this question still open? If yes, please make clear what you want to do. Is your applet embedded in your desktop Java application, or in a web browser?

Answer (score 1):

See [Java-to-Javascript Communication](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html), [Java - Javascript interaction](http://www.raditha.com/java/javascript.php), and [Interaction without LiveConnect](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0184.html) for JavaScript interaction.